# Is this an equivalent way of stating Cauchy's convergence test for series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements from $\mathbb{R}^p$. Then Cauchy's test states that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a natural number $N$ such that $||x_{n+1}+x_{n+2}...+x_{n+p}||<\epsilon$ holds for all $n>N$ and all $p\in \mathbb{N}$.
I was wondering if this is equivalent to saying that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty x_i$ converges if and only if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(x_{n+1}+x_{n+2}...+x_{n+p})=0$, $\forall p\in \mathbb{N}$. To me, they look equivalent, but since I am new to series, I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S_{np} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p} x_k \to \mathbf{0}$ as $n \to \infty$. By definition for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N_p$ such that $n > N_p$ implies $\|S_{np} - \mathbf{0}\| =\|S_{np}\| < \epsilon$.

Since $| \|S_{np} \| - 0| = \|S_{np}\|$ this implies $\|S_{np}\| \to 0$ if and only if $S_{np} \to \mathbf{0}$ for any fixed $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

The Cauchy criterion states that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ (which depends at most on $\epsilon$) such that if $n > N$ we have $\|S_{np}\| < \epsilon$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$.  This is equivalent to saying that $S_{np} \to \mathbf{0}$ as $n \to \infty$ uniformly with respect to $p$.

By the same argument we have $\|S_{np}\| \to 0$ uniformly with respect to $p$ if and only if $S_{np} \to \mathbf{0}$ uniformly with respect to $p$.

The equivalent condition is $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_{np} = \mathbf{0}$ **uniformly** for $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In first sentence is very important which formal restrictions you have on $p$. If you place $\forall p$, then where?

Comment: For any fixed $p$, $\|S_{np}\| \to 0$ if and only if $S_{np} \to \mathbf{0}$ has been shown. If $\|S_{np}\| \to 0$ for every $p$, then $S_{np} \to \mathbf{0}$ for every $p$. and vice versa.

Comment: The only potential problem is the question if the first Cauchy definition is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{np} = \mathbf{0}$ for all $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I only want to emphasize that Cauchy criterion essentially depends on uniform estimation of $p$, that mean quantifier for $p$ should be on right side of quantifier of $N$ . Let me bring example $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$. If we based quantifier for $p$ in left side, then it is true that  $\forall p, x_{n+p}-x_n \to 0$, but as we know $x_n$ diverges.

Comment: @zkutch: Thank you for your insight. I believe I made that qualification.

Comment: Yes. It is nice answer. up voted.

Comment: @RRL So is it basically equivalent to proving $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup\limits_{p\in \mathbb{N}}| S_{np}| = \mathbf{0}$? I tried to write this having in mind the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

Comment: @ChemistryGeek: That is correct.  As zkutch points out $\frac{1}{n+1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n+p} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each fixed $p$ but the supremum over $p$ of that expression does not converge to zero.