# Equivalent ways of stating Cauchy criteria by using limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here [Is this an equivalent way of stating Cauchy's convergence test for series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3771159/is-this-an-equivalent-way-of-stating-cauchys-convergence-test-for-series) I learnt a way to state the Cauchy criterion for series by using the limit. Now, while studying function series and improper integrals I came across similar Cauchy criteria to test convergence and I would like to know how I can rephrase them in a similar way by using some limit.
For instance, we know that $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists K_\epsilon\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\left|\int_c^b f(x) dx\right|<\epsilon$ for all $b\ge c\ge K_\epsilon$. This can be rephrased as $\displaystyle\left|\int_c^{c+p} f(x) dx\right|<\epsilon$ for all $c\ge K_\epsilon$ and $p\in \mathbb{N}$, but I don't know what to do next to imply some limit(I am not even sure that this is possible).
However, in the case of function series it should be possible. I think that we can say that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{p\in \mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{i=0}^p f_{n+i}(x)\right|=0$ for all $x$ in $f_n$'s domain. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

$\int\limits_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges if and only if $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sup_{b>a} |\int\limits_a^{b} f(x+y)dy|=0$. This is similar to the condition you wrote for  series and the proof of this follows from then fact that $\int\limits_a^{b} f(x+y)dy=\int\limits_{a+x}^{b+x} f(t)dt$.

Comment: thank you! What about the condition I wrote for uniform convergence of function series, is it correct?

Comment: @ChemistryGeek Your condition only gives point-wise convergence. For uniform convergence you have to take supremum over all $x$ in the domain before you take limit as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So it should be $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x\in D}\sup_{p\in \mathbb{N}}\left|\sum_{i=0}^p f_{n+i}(x)\right|=0$?

Comment: Yes,that is correct.